# Script to Ping an IP and create a log showing date/time of any fails, times over 500ms, and traceroute any fails

Tags: scripting, ping, traceroute

I am trying to make a script to run constantly that produces a log showing ping stats. I want the log to contain and ping fails, times over 500ms and the traceroute of any timeouts. Here my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ip=www.google.com
while [ 1 ]; do
ping -c 1 $ip 1> /dev/null
result=$?
if [ $result == "1" ]; then
echo FAIL on `date` >> ~/ping.log
echo FAIL on `date`.  Doing tracert!
traceroute $ip >> ~/ping.log
fi
if [ $result == "0" ]; then
echo SUCCEED on `date` >> ~/ping.log
echo SUCCEED on `date`
fi
sleep .4
done
```

I copied this script from another site.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at [fping](http://fping.org/) and it's `-t` option:

> -t n
>
> Initial target timeout in milliseconds (default 500). In the default mode, this is the amount of time that fping waits for a
>   response to its first request.  Successive
>               timeouts are multiplied by the backoff factor.

By using `fping` you can just check the exit status without the need of parsing the output:

```
IP=121.78.67.31; fping -c1 -t200 $IP || traceroute $IP
```

Comment: Sorry I can't use fping. This has to be done in linux and I can not install any programs. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

line

```
ping -c 1 $ip 1> /dev/null
```

discard result, so you can't know if you pings are over 500 ms.

use

```
ping -c 1 $ip 1> /tmp/ping.txt
```

to keep ping's response, then

in the part where ping is sucessfull

```
awk -F/ 'NF>5 { if ( $5 > 500 ) exit 1 ; else exit 0 }'  /tmp/ping.txt
```

will give 0 under 500 ms and 1 if average ping is over 500 ms.

---

ping result looks like

```
PING 172.18.15.22 (172.18.15.22) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.18.15.22: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.237 ms

--- 172.18.15.22 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.237/0.237/0.237/0.000 ms
```

awk will

- `-F/` use / as separator
- `NF>5` pick line with at least /
- `if ( $5 > 500 )` test average value
- `exit 1 / exit 0` givre proper return code

Comment: I am wanting to put in a log file when and individual ping is over a certain time not the average. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: ?? You say "I want the log to contain and ping fails, times over 500ms " So, I use 500 as an example, the comment issue only one ping at a time, my awk solution give you  a way to test if an individual ping is over 500ms. Please do accept my apologies for not understanding your question.