# Create bash script for ping

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, ping

Good evening
I would need a script in bash that follows this command:
`ping -c 4 -i "IP"` for 3 times. Each ping must be performed at a distance of 10 minutes and only when it fails all 3 times, it send an e-mail. Could you help me?

Ex.

```
ping -c 4 -i X.X.X.X
```

Execution type: first ping, if all packet loss, wait 10 minutes and execute again ping command, if still failed execute again last ping and if failed, send an e-mail

```
#!/bin/bash
HOSTS="X.X.X.X"

pingtest(){
  for myHost in "$@"
  do
    ping -c 4 -i 5 $HOSTS && return 1
  done
  return 0
}

if pingtest $HOSTS
then
  # 100% failed
  echo "Server failed" | mail -s "Server Down" myadress@xxxx.com

fi
```

but how can repeat it 3 times and only after it fails with packet loss, send an email?
Thank you

Comment: So you want to ping 4 times 3 times?  What constitutes a failure?  What if 1 of the 4 packets sent in the first run succeed?  Is that a success or a failure?  What does a "distance of 10 minutes" mean?

Comment: This is certainly not a "request for learning material"...it may be "too broad" though.

Comment: Ping command must be run 3 times
Failure is 100% packet loss
Execution type: first ping, if all packet loss, wait  10 minutes and execute again ping command, if still failed execute again last ping and if failed, send an e-mail

Comment: Ok, that's a number of things the script should do. Have you tried to implement any of them? Where have you succeeded and what issues have you faced?

Comment: Did you try to look for previous [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918159/script-for-email-alert-and-ping) [online](http://www.techpository.com/linux-monitor-multiple-servers-using-ping-and-email-on-failure/) [that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345630/script-to-ping-every-hour-and-email-failure) [could](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56340/bash-script-to-detect-when-my-server-is-down-or-offline) be [modified](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206018/script-to-ping-an-ip-and-create-a-log-showing-date-time-of-any-fails-times-over) to work in your case?

Answer (score 0):

If using an external program is acceptable, you could use [monitor-ip](https://github.com/bodhidigital/monitor-ip).  It's written in C and rather configurable.  Unlike a bash script that loops over and continually executes `ping` or a cron job, it can run 100s of pings a second while consuming less than 1% of CPU time.

For example, you could use something like this:

```bsh
sudo ./monitor-ip --interval 5.0 --missed-max 20 --reset -- 1.2.3.4 \
        bash -c 'mail -s "Server Down!" myaddress@xxxx.com <<< "$MONITOR_NOTIFY_REMOTE_ADDRESS unreachable"'
```

This will send pings to `1.2.3.4` at an interval of 5 seconds until 20 consecutive pongs are not received (1 minute of downtime), then send an email to myaddress@xxxx.com.  It would continue to send emails at 1 minute intervals until the status condition is resolved.

Full disclosure: I wrote [monitor-ip](https://github.com/bodhidigital/monitor-ip).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, how to get result from ping:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST="X.X.X.X"
WAITFOR=5
TIMES=3

ping $HOST -c $TIMES -i $WAITFOR &> /dev/null
pingReturn=$?

if [ $pingReturn -eq 0 ]; then
    # It works
    echo "Success!!!"
    exit 0
else
    # No access
    echo "Fail"
    exit 1
fi
```

You can use your method for sending email instead of echo statements, that I have put in. You also have three variables `HOST`, `TIMES`, and `WAITFOR`, which you can set to your desired values. If you want 10 minutes between pings, you have to set `WAITFOR` to value `600`.

Answer (score -2):

Below script works fine for below scenarios

```
 #!/bin/bash
    echo "enter the hostname or IP of the host"
    read h
    ping -c1 $h
    if [ $? != 0 ]
    then
    sleep 6
    ping -c1 $h
    if [ $? != 0 ]
    then
    sleep 6
    ping -c1 $h
    if [ $? != 0 ]
    then
    echo "host $h is not pinging  and its not reachable"
    mail -s "host $h is not pinging  and its not reachable" emailid </dev/null
    else
    echo "host $h is pinging"
    fi
    fi
    fi
```

Comment: You really should lay out your code readably with indentation, etc., particularly if you're trying to help someone else.